# Get the SUM of a string field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, group-by

I have this example MySQL table below:

```
date      |name    |invoice | quantity  | 
-------------------------------
2012-10-02 01:00|aaaa   |101 |  1
2012-10-02 01:30|aaaa   |102 |  2  
2012-10-02 01:45|aaaa   |102 |  3
```

I want to `GROUP BY` date and get a similar results:

```
date      |  name    |invoice | freq_name | freq_quantity  | 
--------------------------------------------------
2012-10-02|  aaaa    |101     |1          | 1
2012-10-02|  aaaa    |102     |2          | 5
```

I have tried to perform this aggregation like below:

```
SELECT 
date, 
name, 
invoice, 
SUM(quantity) AS freq_quantity, 
SUM(name) AS freq_name
FROM table
GROUP BY date, name, invoice
```

The `freq_quantity` field is correct, while the `freq_name` string field not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to `sum` the names, you need to `count` them:

```
SELECT 
date, 
name, 
invoice, 
SUM(quantity) AS freq_quantity, 
COUNT(*) AS freq_name -- Here!
FROM table
GROUP BY date, name, invoice
```